# how to set ini set session maxlife to 10 minutes

Tags: php

To make a session life go up to 10 minutes, is the below code correct because  cannot tell:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',600);
```

OR

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',1*10*60);
```

Comment: The multiplication by `1` is unnecessary, but yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct, but the first one will run faster ( by a nanosecond )

Comment: How come when I do it the first way that after 10 minutes that the session does not expire?

Comment: weird, that function takes the parameter in seconds ( [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) ) and it should not matter if you're using the final number or do some math before